# How to clear "Slot 'default' invoked outside of the render function" warning? Vue3, Composition API

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup, vuejs-slots

The full warning message:

`[Vue warn]: Slot "default" invoked outside of the render function: this will not track dependencies used in the slot. Invoke the slot function inside the render function instead.`

Nothing is broken and the functionality runs fine.  I am just trying to clear this error.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <ul class="flex" data-test-id="tab-wrapper">
    <li
      v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
      :key="index"
      @click="currentTab = tab"
    >
      {{ tab }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <slot />
</template>


<script setup>
import { provide, ref, useSlots } from "vue";

const slots = useSlots();
const tabs = (slots.default && slots.default().map(tab => tab?.props?.title)) ?? [];
const currentTab = ref(tabs[0]);

provide("currentTab", currentTab);
</script>
```

It is my understanding that render() is implicit in the template, but I don't know how to implement the way I am using slots in the template `v-for`.

Other questions that I have seen about this involve `setup(props, context)` or actually rendering the template using `render()` inside the script tag.

I'm brand new to Vue3/Composition API so I'm sure I did something wrong, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 cli-service app: "Slot "default" invoked outside of the render function" warning when component with slots is imported from other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928229/vue-3-cli-service-app-slot-default-invoked-outside-of-the-render-function-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I've done it using render functions, just for sake of trying.

I would not do it this way in real, since it's too complicated and feels very like bad designed.

```js
const { createApp, ref, h, resolveComponent } = Vue;

const Tab = {
  props: ['title'],
  template: 'Tab: {{ title }}'
}

const Tabpane = {
  components: { Tab },
  setup(props, { slots, expose }) {
    const currentTab = ref(null);
    const tab = resolveComponent('Tab')
    return () => h('div', null, 
      [
        h('div', null, 'Current Tab: ' + (currentTab.value ? currentTab.value.props?.title : '') ),
        h('ul', { class: 'flex', 'data-test-id' : 'tab-wrapper' }, 
         slots.default()?.map(tab => 
          h('li', 
            { onClick: () => { currentTab.value = tab } }, 
            tab.props.title)) ?? []          
        ),
        currentTab.value ? h(tab, 
          { title: currentTab.value?.props.title }, 
          currentTab 
        ) : null
     ])
  }
}

const App = { 
  components: { Tabpane }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
li { cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline; color: blue;}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<tabpane>
<tab title="One"></tab>
<tab title="Two"></tab>
</tabpane>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="tabpane">
  <ul class="flex" data-test-id="tab-wrapper">
    <li
      v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index" @click="currentTab = tab">
      {{ tab }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <slot></slot>
</script>
```

---

This is a duplicate of the [Vue 3 cli-service app: "Slot "default" invoked outside of the render function" warning when component with slots is imported from other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928229/vue-3-cli-service-app-slot-default-invoked-outside-of-the-render-function-w)

You should not use `slots.default()` outside the `render()` function.

That's what the Vue warning says.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That answers my question on a conceptual level (I saw that post before), and I see how he did it with setup() inside defineComponent(), but I don't know how to transfer that implementation into the way my code is written.  That's what I have been researching.  I tried to actually write slots.default().map in the v-for tag but that did not work

Comment: Why not simply pass the tab titles over a prop?

Comment: The component above is TabWrapper.vue.  I am calling it inside a component as a wrapper for Tab.vue.  The tab title is passed to each <Tab/> inside <TabWrapper></TabWrapper>, so to access those values I need to check the slots in TabWrapper.  It seems like the solution may be to refactor the way I did this.

Comment: Check the Vue Docs: [Dynamic Components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) section for an example how to implement a tabulator. This is the recommended way to solve tasks like yours.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation to comment, but the solution is put the context on the `<slot></slot>`

[- The documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots)

[- here an example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UbtuwzAM/BVWS5bI2gM3QPsLWbXYDt06tR6QKDdFkH8vZTVGnKIFPIhH3pm8u4gX76spodiJOnZh8LTXdjDeBYJDas1Ar4nIWeiDM7Cp1D2YiRttAbTF80w5Yt+kkeCS0c6xjkVLcVcAWElm5Kotf7Vafs0FofFjQ8gVQP0kJaSI0Dfj2DbdBxCeCaQs3dWKasYWlg9uGo4IXYrEu//J2x+aCevVYTxUq2UPsRXFEWkaX52is+zWfJD+aUQtlhO1YFdyrcU7kY87pWLfZatOsXLhTfGrCsnSYLDCaGQb3GfEwMJabO80FIMTBhnQHjFg+E/zYfSX7s1rPuUxwJz82vK22ElfHp+1iPO8Fjkc4m4cXQ5qXpOKWPF7Sahzljj1m9maON9Cys+i/uDw9RsFZuEc)

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is wrong. -1

Comment: Thanks Everton, but I had read that doc as well.  The person is calling the slots.default() inside the `return` of the setup() function.  Different scenario from mine code-wise.  Still trying to figure out how to do it.