# How can I inject template into a slot

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In vue 2.7 I have a table component

```
<template>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <slot name="tbody"></slot>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

Using this component like so:

```
<my-table>
    <template #tbody>
         <tr v-for="employee in employees" :key="employee.id">
              <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ employee.occupation }}</td>
         </tr>
     </template>
</my-table>
```

Now in the component I want to add a checkbox for every row in the template supplied from outside the component. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but complicated. You will need to manually process your slots and render them again using Vue [Render Functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html).

Check for example this [How to clear "Slot 'default' invoked outside of the render function" warning? Vue3, Composition API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75804628/2487565) on how to process passed slots in a component.

It's a lot of work. I would suggest you rethink your design.

Check how popular Vue Libraries, like [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/), [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/), [PrimeVue](https://primevue.org/), [Element+](https://element-plus.org/en-US/) design the Tables.

They mostly pass data to a table component and provide slots for cells.

Answer (score 0):

For Vue 2 it's possible using v-bind="" and example:

```
<slot name="tbod`enter code here`y" v-bind="{ checkbox: true }"></slot>
```

and add a field using the id, similar this:

```
<td v-if="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" :value="employee.id" v-model="selectedEmployees">
</td>
```

and add a selectedEmployees data property to store all the selected employee IDs