# change vue 3 slot content programmatically

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

How to programmatically change vue 3 slot content?

Get slots via useSlot, set ref, update ref.value (`slotref.value = [...slotref.value, slotref.value[0]]`), nothing changed.

Comment: Please share the whole code, and explain why do need this?

Comment: Please tell more about your goal.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done using Vue [Render Functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html). Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75814906/2487565).

But, if you want to change the content of the slot from the component, then **you don't need the slot**!

You should possibly rethink your component design.